# Boyer moore string search using openMP

Tags: c, openmp

I am implementing the Boyer–Moore algorithm using OpenMP and C.  I am using the gcc compiler. My serial code works fine, but when parallelizing using OpenMP, I used

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

But the output I am getting is not correct. I am getting different keyword counts for different runs and also the offset of the keyword is incorrect. 
Are there any special rules for this `#pragma omp parallel for` directive?

This is code of the for loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for(k=0;k<=s.st_size;k+=chunksize-plen)
    {
        fseek(fp,k,SEEK_SET);
        fread(data, chunksize, sizeof(unsigned char), fp);
        data[chunksize]='\0';
        boyermoore(data,pattern,k,&c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could at least post the code of the `for` loop? One example problem might be that the iteration variable of the `for` loop cannot be modified within the loop and the increment must be loop invariant.

Comment: This is code of thefor loop

#pragma omp parallel 
{
#pragma omp  for
for(k=0;k<=s.st_size;k+=chunksize-plen)

 { 

                   fseek(fp,k,SEEK_SET); 
 
  fread(data, chunksize, sizeof(unsigned char), fp); 
 
  data[chunksize]='\0';
 
  boyermoore(data,pattern,k,&c);

 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to minimize the amount of data that is shared within the parallel region. For this code, I think you need to make `data` private, and if it's a memory buffer, make sure it's separate for each thread:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(data)
{
    data = malloc( chunksize ); /* or whatever size it should be */
    #pragma omp for
    { /* ... */ }
    free(data);
}
```

Alternatively, you might allocate the buffer for all threads at once before the parallel region, and use `omp_get_thread_num` to find out which part of the buffer should be used:

```
buffer = malloc ( chunksize * omp_get_max_threads() );
#pragma omp parallel private(data)
{
    data = (char*)buffer + omp_get_thread_num()*chunksize;
    /* ... */
}
```

Maybe `pattern` and `c` should be private as well; it's hard to say without seeing the code of `boyermoore` function.

Second, you need to synchronize access to any shared variables (unless those are only for reading). In particular, any operations with a file should be synchronized, e.g. with the help of `#pragma omp critical`:

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    fseek(fp,k,SEEK_SET);
    fread(data, chunksize, sizeof(unsigned char), fp);
}
```

Third, you need to make sure that `boyermoore` function and any functions it calls are thread-safe and can be executed concurrently without data races. Typically, any access to a shared state (e.g. global variables) need to be synchronized. Also if any pointers are passed to the function (e.g. `&c` seems suspicious) you need to make sure that either those point to different memory in each thread or the modifications of that memory are synchronized as well.

Comment: actually 'data' needs to be passed as private. because each thread must have its own copy of data. But when I give data as private, it shows a segmentation fault. i am a beginner in openMp and i cant understand the reason for this segmentation fault. Is it because of the private memory constrain for a thread?? How can I solve this??

Comment: Impossible to find the issue without seeing how `data` is managed in your code. See general recommendations above: either allocate a separate array for each thread, or pre-allocate a big one and "split" it to parts accessed by individual threads without conflicts.

Comment: On StackOverflow, the way to thank somebody is to up-vote answers that are useful to you, and accept a one that works best for you. Of course it's your decision whether an answer deserves a vote or acceptance. See more information at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I modified my code as you said. But now I have a new problem. My code works fine for an input file of size up to 2GB. But when 3 GB file is used as input, my output varies from run to run.

Answer (score 1):

These statements are not safely parallelizable (is that a word?):

```
    fseek(fp,k,SEEK_SET);
    fread(data, chunksize, sizeof(unsigned char), fp);
```

One thread setting the position at the same time as another or immediately before read in another thread will wreak havoc.  Not to mention that each thread would be reading into the same `data` buffer.